# React navigation adding "more" tab with a pop up list and not navigate to tab

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-navigation

I am basically trying to add a "more" button for both iOS and ANDROID, which pops up a list of options to choose from. Something that looks like this
([IOS more button](https://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2014/05/facebook-tab-bar1.png?)) and ([ANDROID more button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipLe6.png)).

I am using React Navigation to create the TabNavigator TabBar and I know how to add a new tab, I'm just not sure how to create a small menu list thats generated when i click on the tab button instead of navigating me to the tab button screen.

Any ideas on how to go about that?

Comment: Why don't you create a custom "more" screen with a simple listview and add it as the 5th tab item?

Comment: This would still navigate to the tab and display my options in that tab ( which is not what i want) ? did I understand what you were suggesting correctly ?

Comment: Yes, but I think it's the only way. The facebook app what you linked for ios example works the same way. What would you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: well im trying to do something like this https://garvitabajaj.files.wordpress.com/2015/01/menu1.png
When you click on the three buttons a  small list of options renders close to the "more" button. Im trying to make the same thing for ios and android (but it renders upwards in ios ofcourse)

Comment: I don't think it's possible in the tab bar, people usually use it in navigation bars. Here is a library to make it in the navigation bar: https://github.com/jaysoo/react-native-menu

Comment: I'll try adding that in the tab bar and see how it goes. Thank you

Comment: @user3676224 do you know how to create a custom tab ?  when you create a custom tab you are in control of everything including where it navigates to or what the button does so what you are thinking is very possible with react navigation

Comment: @CalebToluIsrael, I would appreciate any instructions on creating a custom tab! is that a part of the react-navigation's docs "Custom Navigators"?

Answer (score 0):

This is for anyone who might get here through Google search. You can prevent the default behavior of a tab press (for example to create a `More` button instead of navigating away).

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('tabPress', e => {
    // Prevent default behavior
    e.preventDefault();

    // Do something manually
    // ...
  });

  return unsubscribe;
}, [navigation]);
```

[Try example here](https://snack.expo.io/?platform=android&name=createStackNavigator%20%7C%20React%20Navigation&dependencies=%40react-native-community%2Fmasked-view%40%5E0.1.1%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative%40%5E5.0.5%2C%40react-navigation%2Fbottom-tabs%40%5E5.0.5%2C%40react-navigation%2Fdrawer%40%5E5.0.5%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-bottom-tabs%40%5E5.0.5%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-top-tabs%40%5E5.0.5%2C%40react-navigation%2Fstack%40%5E5.0.5%2Creact-native-gesture-handler%401.5.2%2Creact-native-reanimated%401.4.0%2Creact-native-safe-area-context%400.6.0%2Creact-native-screens%402.0.0-alpha.12&sourceUrl=https%3A%2F%2Freactnavigation.org%2Fexamples%2F5.x%2Fbottom-tab-prevent-default.js)

--- OR ----

```
<Tabs.Screen
  name="Chat"
  component={Chat}
  listeners={{
    tabPress: e => {
      // Prevent default action
      e.preventDefault();
    },
  }}
/>
```

Read more on navigation events [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-events)